# Writing two classes in separate files that have conversions to each other?

Tags: python, class, import, python-import

Let's say I have two files, each with a class in it. `int.py`, which has a custom implementation of an integer class, and `float.py`, which has a custom implementation of a float class.

I want each class to have a conversion method to the other. For example:

```
class Integer:   
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def to_f():
    return Float(self.value)
```

and

```
class Float:   
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def to_i():
    return Integer(self.value)
```

How can I import the files into each other so that the constructors are available, without causing a circular dependency?

Comment: Put them both in the same file - you're about to run into circular import issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the class when the method is called:

```
class Float:   
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def to_i(self):
    from integer import Integer
    return Integer(self.value)
```

Imports are cached in `sys.modules`, so it won't have any performance penalty beyond the first call to `Float.to_i`.

---

An alternative is to import the module itself and look up the class:

```
import integer

class Float:   
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def to_i(self):
    return integer.Integer(self.value)
```

As long as there are no module-level circular dependencies (like subclassing `Float` in `integer`), you won't have any issues.

---

Yet another (potentially confusing) alternative is to import the classes after the modules:

```
class Float:   
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def to_i(self):
    return Integer(self.value)


from integer import Integer
```

By the time `Float.to_i` is called, `Integer` will be in scope. I only recall seeing the first two methods used in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the classes locally:

```
class Float:  
  def to_i():
    from .int import Integer  # not run at module loading time
    return Integer(self.value)

class Integer:   
  def to_f():
    from .float import Float
    return Float(self.value)
```

This prevents the imports from being run at module loading time and, thus, avoids circular imports.